# When retrieving the class name and id of an element I always get undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code to debug...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider').slider();
});

$.fn.slider = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var dragging = false;
    var startX = $el.offset().left;
    var startL = 0;
    $el.mousedown(function(ev) {
        dragging = true;
        startX = ev.clientX;
        startL = $(this).css('left');
        alert("class: "+ $el.className +"   id: " + $el.id);
    });

    $(document).mousemove(function(ev) {
        if (dragging) {
            var newLeft = parseInt(startL) + (ev.clientX - startX);
            $el.css('left', newLeft );
        }
    }).mouseup(function() {
        dragging = false;
    });
  });
}
```

Note: `alert("class: "+ $el.className +"   id: " + $el.id);`

It always returns "undefined" for `$el.className` and `$el.id`.

How can I get it to return the id and class of the element (div) that I've clicked on?

I've tried many variant of `$el` and `.id`, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Having learned a lot more about JavaScript since I asked this question, I've  realized that console.log() is much more useful than debugging with alert().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing jQuery and vanilla javascript properties.  `className` is vanilla and `$(this)` makes a jQuery object.

Either change

```
$el.className
```

to

```
$el.attr('class')
```

or if you want to use `className`:

```
var $el = $(this);
```

to

```
var $el = this;
```

(although that would require changing other parts of code as well)

Comment: That was it, thank you!  I'll approve the answer when the time restriction runs out.

Answer (score 1):

try like following:

```
$(function() {
$("div").click(function() {
     var name = this.name;
     var cls = this.className;
     var id= this.id;

     alert("Name: " + name + " / Class: " + cls + " / Id: " + id);
    });
});
```